# Jquery functions not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with the timing execution of my jquery functions. my function dosent always fire correctly or sometimes not at all.I also have a datable that I execute seperately but nothing is synchronizing correctly. The way I have it setup at the moment is that I have all my functions on a seperate html page named modal_form.html. I did this way as I have many pages that call upon these functions and loads other similar content.

Here is an example of the function on my modal_form.html

```
var IncidentManager = {
    // Returns the url of the application server of a demo web app.
    basePath: function () { return '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc'; },
    // Loads all incidents closed or opened. This is mainly used for the report page.
    loadReportIncidents: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$orderby=PrioritéValue desc',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, incident) {

                $('#example tbody').append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'> <button class='edit_button btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xs' name ='btnSubmit' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='"+incident.ID+"'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.Incident + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.PrioritéValue + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.Composante + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control text-left'>" + incident.Description + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.Date_de_début + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.ResponsableValue + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");                   
                })
            }
        });
    },  
};
```

Here some of the code in my reports page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#load_modal").load("pages/modal_form.html");  

$( document ).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() { 
IncidentManager.loadReportIncidents();
}, 500);
</script>
```

I had to use a a setTimeout to load the `IncidentManager.loadReportIncidents();`without it it was not loading at all. But what happens is that my function dosent seem to be always firing correctly and ususally needs a few refreshes for it t work. I keep increasing the delay but dosent seem to be the most efficent method to approach.

I would imagine that loading an HTML file externally is what is causing my problems but Id ont see any solutions to this. Would anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax load is async, use the success function to execute the function when modal finished loading

try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#load_modal").load("pages/modal_form.html",function(){
IncidentManager.loadReportIncidents();
}); 
});
```

Comment: How would you run another function after `IncidentManager.loadReportIncidents();` completes?

Comment: in the success function of that ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Use success/ complete block of ajax function in jQuery.